# Convert rows to columns sql server to be used in Excel chart

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a query that returns the following

[image]

and need to pivot the data as follows

[image]

in order to use it in excel later on and plot DB size evolution in a chart.
Can this be done? I have never used the PIVOT function.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have a lot of those databases, the easiest thing isn't PIVOT but this :

```
SELECT The_Month,
       SUM(CASE WHEN The_Database='Admin' THEN Backup_size_DB ELSE 0 END) AS Admin,
       SUM(CASE WHEN The_Database='AWorks' THEN Backup_size_DB ELSE 0 END) AS AWorks,
       -- and so on ...
FROM The_query
GROUP BY The_Month
ORDER BY The_Month
```

Comment: Thanks, in fact I have a lot of DBs, 50